# Way to subdivide beveled face automaticaly

Tags: modeling, workflow, bevel

Im beveling simple cuboid and in order to create edge loops after that i must manually reconstruct some of the faces. Im just a beginner so maybe i missed something in documentation. What i want after beveling is something like that:

[image: ideal result]

so my loop cuts won't complain. Just vertical or horizontal subdivision would be suffice i guess. Any help or nod to the right direction is much appreciated

Comment: If you want to create the edges you are showing, use the knife tool, but maybe it is not even useful, it depends on what you want to do next

Comment: well that's what i thought. i was hoping for some kind of checkbox for blender to apply its magic. thanks